# How to turn off panels in-place edit bar

Tags: 7, panels

I know this maybe a silly question but how do you hide panels in-place editor bar?(The bar that has layout adjustment buttons.) I found a post that said there's a on/off setting on general settings page that I can use to hide it but I couldn't find that option. I need to hide it because that toolbar is covering Theme developer checkbox. I can't disable the module either because it's in used. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Panelizer" tab of your content type then click on "Full page override" (or whatever view mode that is panelized" and then under settings you will see:

```
Standard
In-Place Editor
```

Click the standard.

The In-Place Editor setting is what is creating the tool bar at the bottom.

Comment: "Full page override" is just a heading with bunch of checkbox options. But under Structure/Panels/General, I found that settings but it doesn't hide the bar.